# Python opening XML remotely for reading and parsing

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am attempting to open a xml file remotely for reading and parsing but getting an error when I try to use it. When I print it also starts with some unrecognized characters.  Can you please help point me in the right direction so that I can open xml file remotely and parse the data?

XML File:

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Data.xsl"?>
<abc>
  <md>
    <mi>
      <datetime>20160822020003</datetime>
      <period>3600</period>
      <it>Item_No_1</it>
      <it>Item_No_2</it>
      <it>Item_No_3</it>
      <it>Item_No_4</it>
      <it>Item_No_5</it>
      <it>Item_No_6</it>
      <it>Item_No_7</it>
      <ovalue>
        <v>1111111111</v>
        <v>2222222222</v>
        <v>3333333333</v>
        <v>4444444444</v>
        <v>5555555555</v>
        <v>6666666666</v>
        <v>7777777777</v>
      </ovalue>
    </mi>
  </md>
</abc>
```

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('test.xml') as f:
    for line in f:
        x = line
        print(x, end='')

    root = ET.fromstring(x)
    print(root.tag)
```

Error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The first two bytes in your example file are a Unicode [Byte Order Marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) indicating the file is encoded as UTF-8.

It seems lxml trips over this. Just slice the first two bytes off, lxml will detect the correct encoding from the Doctype declaration anyway.

```
root = ET.fromstring(x[3:])
```

Comment: Tried this but did not fix the issue. Still getting the same error. BTW I am not using lxml. Is there something else I can try?

Comment: Oops, I always use llxml and as it follows the API of `ElementTree` I haven't seen this. If you want to parse third party and therefore untrusted XML data you should, too: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html#xml-vulnerabilities

Comment: And the byte order maker is three bytes long.